# Superimpose variables within a single pie chart

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to create a pie chart superimposing multiple variables using r-plotly.

For instance, I have values for the global population of a country, it's economically active population, and the economically active male/female.

I want to get all those data inside a single pie chart, with the full cercle as the golbal population, a part of this cercle representing the active population, which is divided itslef in 2 parts, male/female.

I unfortunnatly have no idea how to archieve it and I don't even know is it's possible.
I didn't manage to do it using the function :

```
plot_ly(...)
```

Thank you for your help and happy new year !

Answer (score 1):

I think a "sunburst" plot could be what you are looking for.

Here is an example on a fake dataset:

```
library(sunburstR)

dat <- data.frame(G = c("male-active", "male-inactive", "female-active", "female-inactive"),
                  N = c(100, 100, 100, 100))

sunburst(dat)
```

[image: The result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Indeed this kind of chart wouldbe nice. I'll check the package documentation for more information. It's for a shiny application, i know plotly is nice for those applications but this one seems to be interactive also.

Comment: It's interactive and there is a special function to render a shiny version of this kind of plots.